# disable prev button in bootstrap tour

Tags: bootstrap-tour

Have a tour like this

```
var TourToolTipPoolConfiguration = new Tour({
            name: 'TourToolTipPoolConfiguration',
            steps: [
                {
                    onNext: function (TourToolTipPoolConfiguration) {
                        TourToolTipPoolConfiguration.goTo(3);
                    },
                    element: "#TimeExpireTicket",
                    title: "foo",
                    content: "test1"
                },
                {
                    element: "#DayNumber",
                    title: "foo",
                    content: "test2"
                },
                {
                    element: "#SavePoolConfig",
                    title: "foo",
                    content: "test3"
                }
            ]
        });
```

step1 or step2 is optional, i hidde the div display:none, but if tour init in step 2, i need disable prev button because step1 is hidden, how make that? i try onPrev evaluate if div if visible but not work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can simply hide it using css:

```
button[data-role='prev'] {
  display: none;
}
```